# Efficiently handling python exception

Tags: python, exception

Is it justifiable to catch an exception and raise the very same exception (with possibly a different descriptive string from the original message? 
In my mind thats creating atleast one other object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is nothing wrong with doing something like this. (Remember to use exception chaining to pass the original exception as well).

Yes, it will use CPU cycles - however, it's unlikely to be an issue, and you should avoid premature optimisation, in favour of clearer and more effective code.